# selenium webdriver run time error on eclips

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: E:\chromedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
    at MyPackage1.MyClass1.main(MyClass1.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Google Chrome (if you don't have this browser installed).
Download [Chromedriver executable](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and extract it.
Set system property in your code (before you use ChromeDriver):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to the ChromeDriver file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you've added wrong path for your chrome driver executable or you don't have any. Download it from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and run the code with below snippets for path to executable.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to the executable driver file");
```